# Background image not showing when specified in CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

## Problem

I am trying to set the background image of a `div` in CSS, but it does not work.

## Code

```css
.img-background {
    background-image: url('Portfolio5.jpg');
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My Site</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="img-background"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might be url of image was wrong. @Vamsi Teja

Comment: pls share your image folder path

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/3gkov1tr/)

In your `.image-background` class, you are setting the height as `100%`; this will cause it to become 100% the height of the parent element, which is the body. However, the body doesn't have a height specified, so it defaults to `0` and as a result, your image is not visible. To solve this, you need to set the height of `html` and the `body` to `100%` as well.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The `margin` has been set to `0` to avoid the `body` overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you use `height:100%`

for example :

```
.bg-img {
    width: 100%;

    height: 100vh;

    background: url('./img.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**Edit:** 
`vh` stands for Viewport Height (vh) and it means 100% of parent's height.`background-image` needs certain height and width to show content, so a tag without inner html does't show its content.

Comment: Please expand on why `height: 100%` does not work and why `height: 100vh` does work.

Comment: `100vh` doesn't mean 100% of the parent's height, it means 100% of the viewport (website) height.